# What is an eightBitByteArray in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

While reading [this](http://codeidol.com/java/swing/Audio/Build-an-Audio-Waveform-Display/) example of music visualization in Java.
I was wondering where the Author got the variable eightBitByteArray from.
Can someone explain me how to create this Array or for what it stands for?

```
for (int t = 0; t < eightBitByteArray.length;) {
    for (int channel = 0; channel < numChannels; channel++) {
        int low = (int) eightBitByteArray[t];
        t++;
        int high = (int) eightBitByteArray[t];
        t++;
        int sample = getSixteenBitSample(high, low);
       toReturn[channel][sampleIndex] = sample;
   }
   sampleIndex++;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any reference to `eightBitByteArray` in that link but I would assume it is just a `byte[]` being that each element has eight bits, it has a `length` field and the variable name says "ByteArray".

Comment: @FalkJäger in the link he says that he's using `byte[]` outright!

Answer (score 0):

I was also confused with this tutorial and have found a complete example [here](https://www.javatips.net/api/etyllica-master/src/main/java/sound/capture/AudioHandler.java). The `eightBitByteArray` appears to be `buffer` used to read audio data from the `TargetDataLine`.

I would guess it was renamed to this for clarity (because sample size was chosen to be `16` bits, but a `byte` can only store `8` and the name explicitly reflects that).